# Adding a storyboard to existing code

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I was wondering how I would be able to add a story board to an existing code?
I have experience in c++, c and java and I wanted to try programming an App.
On github I saw a project that I wanted to implement onto mine which is a side navigation.
(https://github.com/twotoasters/TWTSideMenuViewController)

This project didn't have a storyboard so I was wondering if it was possible to add one and see exactly what it shows on the iphone simulator. Thanks in advance. (new to xcode/ object c trying to teach myself)

Comment: You can add Storyboard to any project but you must remember that stuff like `TWTSideMenuViewController` doesn't have a graphical representation and you still have to set them in code.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the project
New File -> User Interface -> Story Board